# Compute the azimuth between two UTM32N points using Java GeoTools

Tags: java, geotools, azimuth

I am using Java GeoTools to compute the azimuth between two UTM32N points, e.g. between `POINT(496383,5419109)` and `POINT(528196,6070949)`.  Is it possible to do so without converting the points to WGS84 first?

The following code does *not* run because `Latitude 5419109°00.0'N is out of range (±90°)`:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:32632");
GeodeticCalculator gc = new GeodeticCalculator();
gc.setStartingPosition(new DirectPosition2D(crs, p1.getX(), p1.getY()));
gc.setDestinationPosition(new DirectPosition2D(crs, p2.getX(), p2.getY()));
return gc.getAzimuth();
```

After a ton of trial-and-error I was able to get the code to run by converting the points to WGS84 first:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:32632");
MathTransform transformToWgs84 = CRS.findMathTransform(crs, DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
Coordinate p1Wgs84 = JTS.transform(p1.getCoordinate(), null, transformToWgs84);
Coordinate p2Wgs84 = JTS.transform(p2.getCoordinate(), null, transformToWgs84);
GeodeticCalculator gc = new GeodeticCalculator();
gc.setStartingPosition(new DirectPosition2D(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84, p1Wgs84.getX(), p1Wgs84.getY()));
gc.setDestinationPosition(new DirectPosition2D(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84, p2Wgs84.getX(), p2Wgs84.getY()));
return gc.getAzimuth();
```

However, this "solution" is somewhat unsatisfactory.  Is there a way to directly compute the azimuth between two UTM32N points?

Comment: What kind of accuracy are you after? UTM is cartesian, you could use simple plane geometry.

Comment: @inc42 This is true.  I haven't considered it and will look into it.  How big of an error am I looking at if I stay within the same zone?

Answer (score 3):

Following `inc42`'s comment, I implemented some simple Cartesian acrobatics to obtain the azimuth between two UTM32N points:

```
double[] v12 = {p2.getX() - p1.getX(), p2.getY() - p1.getY()};
double deg = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(v12[1] / Math.sqrt(v12[0]*v12[0] + v12[1]*v12[1])));
return v12[0]<0.0 ? -deg : deg;
```

Checking the resulting azimuths for 100 randomly picked points within Germany, the difference between both methods appears to be within 2°.  This is an error I can live with...

Comment: Using Math.atan(v12[1],v12[0]) should give more accurate results.